# java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I am getting below exception-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:2820)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.peoplecloud.app.guggu.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:75)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4803)
```

I have added the following code,however i am still getting this exception-

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

If I remove the content inside recycler view then there is no exception.

Comment: why added views inside recycler view in layout.

Comment: @NoName those views  is the content which i want to appear in navigation drawer.

Comment: then write those things out side recycler view

Answer (score 11):

Remove the child elements from `RecyclerView` in your layout file. I don't know what those are supposed to be, but they are not supposed to be children of the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Having `setHasFixedSize()` before the `LayoutManager` statement fixed the issue for me.