# Why am I getting the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager on (HelpActivity.java:28)

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-xml

I'm developing a **material design** app. I want to display a list using `RecyclerView` in `HelpActivity`.

The problem is that I'm getting the following errors: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager` on line `(HelpActivity.java:28)`.

**Here's `HelpActivity.java` file's code:**

```
public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.helpActivityContent);

        // use a linear layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter = new HelpContentAdapter(helpContents);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        initializeData();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);*/

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    class HelpActivityContent {
        String option;
        String subOption;
        int icon;

        HelpActivityContent(String option, String subOption, int icon) {
            this.option = option;
            this.subOption = subOption;
            this.icon = icon;
        }
    }

    public List<HelpActivityContent> helpContents;

    // This method creates an ArrayList that has three Person objects
// Checkout the project associated with this tutorial on Github if
// you want to use the same images.
    private void initializeData(){
        helpContents = new ArrayList<>();
        helpContents.add(new HelpActivityContent("123", "", R.drawable.ic_action_a));
        helpContents.add(new HelpActivityContent("123", "", R.drawable.ic_action_b));
        helpContents.add(new HelpActivityContent("321", "111", R.drawable.ic_action_c));
        helpContents.add(new HelpActivityContent("1", "2", R.drawable.ic_action_d));
    }

    public class HelpContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HelpContentAdapter.HelpContentViewHolder>{

        public class HelpContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView option;
            TextView subOption;
            ImageView icon;

            HelpContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                option = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option);
                subOption = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subOption);
                icon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionIcon);
            }

        }

        List<HelpActivityContent> helpContents;

        HelpContentAdapter(List<HelpActivityContent> helpContents){
            this.helpContents = helpContents;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return helpContents.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HelpContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_help, viewGroup, false);
            HelpContentViewHolder pvh = new HelpContentViewHolder(v);
            return pvh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(HelpContentViewHolder helpContentViewHolder, int i) {
            helpContentViewHolder.option.setText(helpContents.get(i).option);
            helpContentViewHolder.subOption.setText(helpContents.get(i).subOption);
            helpContentViewHolder.icon.setImageResource(helpContents.get(i).icon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                supportFinishAfterTransition();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

**Here's `content_help.xml` file's code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/helpActivityContent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_help"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.HelpActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/optionIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/optionIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subOption"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/optionIcon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/option"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I'm unable to figure out what the problem is.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working on Eclipse or Android Studio ?

Comment: @TasosMoustakas Android Studio.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AS yet, sorry. But, i'm sure there is a way to debug your project and watch step by step all changes made to your variables.
Check http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: U have a import like this? import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

Comment: @Brendon Yes, I have.

Comment: Are you familiar with listview?

Comment: Then just try like this mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: @Brendon it didn't worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924562/recyclerview-has-no-layoutmanager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123080/java-lang-illegalstateexception-recyclerview-has-no-layoutmanager)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put your child elements directly inside the recycler view.
You need to create separate row layout like the one you create in listview.

Just remove the xml code written inside recycler view and insert it inside row_layout xml file and then inflate that row layout file inside your adapter instead.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_help"
tools:context="com.abc.xyz.HelpActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/optionIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/option"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/optionIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subOption"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/optionIcon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/option"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just create separate file for row_layout containing above content and inflate it like below inside your **oncreateviewholder**:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.**<new_layout_you_will_create>**, viewGroup, false);
```

Comment: @HammadNasir That should be the only source of error..let me know if that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I just made a small change in your content_help.xml and it works fine for me.. 
content_help.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_help"
tools:context="com.abc.xyz.HelpActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/optionIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/option"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/optionIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subOption"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/optionIcon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/option"
    />
```

If you are using the recyclerview in activity_help.xml, no need to use the same for your row-content.

Hope this will solve your problem